# ios swift app orientation change very slow; what happens when iOS device changes orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, orientation

I have a UIViewController that contains a UIScrollView, into which I build all my content for display. I do this because the content is dynamic and depends on data stored in the database.

When I change orientation on an iPhone or in the simulator it takes a long time to perform the change (depending on the data for the display it can be up to 40 seconds).

If I just launch the same controller it takes only a few seconds (it has an overlay and progress indicator so the user knows it's thinking).

Why should the orientation take so long? What actually happens when an orientation change occurs?

Answer (score 0):

How do you load the data from your database, synchronously or asynchronously? You should load it asynchronously if you want a better responsiveness from your app.

Also, if the database is accessed synchronously from the main thread, then where is located that code that loads the data: somewhere in ‘viewDidLoad’, ‘viewDidLayoutSubviews’, etc.? I suspect that that loading code runs multiple times when the orientation of the device changes, so you can try to put a breakpoint there and see what exactly happens...

Comment: The UI is generated/updated asynchronously and shows an alpha overlay and progress indicator while building. The database access is very quick, its the transformation into views that takes longer. I build the views from viewDidLayoutSubviews() and it is not run unnecessarily. I've a log message when it builds and during orientation changes there is no call to that code, so there is something in iOS that is troubled by my layouts.